# Scrapy pipeline html parsing

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I have a spider with 3 items: url, title and category.

They are loading fine in raw html but now I would like to convert title and category into plain text using html2test in a pipeline..

Here is my incorrect pipeline code, could someone help debugging it.

Thank you

```
import html2text
import csv
from tutorial import settings

def write_to_csv(item):
    writer = csv.writer(open(settings.csv_file_path, 'a'), lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([item[key] for key in item.keys()])


class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        h = html2text.HTML2Text()
        h.ignore_images = True
        h.handle(item['title']).strip()
        h.handle(item['category']).strip()
        write_to_csv(item)
        return item
```

Spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class tuto(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tuto"
    allowed_domains = ['emedicine.medscape.com']
    start_urls=["http://emedicine.medscape.com"]
    rules=(
        Rule( LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths ='//div[@id="browsespecialties"]'),callback='follow_pages', follow=True),
    )
    def follow_pages(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="maincolbox"]//a/@href').extract():
            yield Request("http://emedicine.medscape.com/" + sel, callback = self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = TutorialItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['background'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="refsection_content"]').extract()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse the HTML in the pipeline.

Extract the `text()` of the elements in the spider.

Replace:

```
item['background'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="refsection_content"]').extract()
item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1').extract()
```

with:

```
item['background'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="refsection_content"]/text()').extract()
item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pipeline code is not assigning the result of the html to text conversion. To update the items, you should change the bit doing the conversion to:

```
...
item['title'] = h.handle(item['title']).strip()
item['category'] = h.handle(item['category']).strip()
...
```